# How to get the data only on working hours

Tags: mysql, date, datetime

Is there a way to select or query the data only on working hours?

| id | description | datetime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alarm Activated | 2022-01-02 14:00:00 |
| 2 | Alarm Deactivated | 2022-01-02 15:00:00 |
| 3 | Alarm Activated | 2022-01-03 18:00:00 |
| .. | Alarm Activated | 2022-01-31 11:00:00 |

I'd like to get the number of the alarm activated on or during working hours from mon-fri 8am to 5pm.

I tried to use the between date but no luck.

Comment: if that can be done with windows in active directory AD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sql
SELECT *        -- if you need to count them only - use SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM datatable
WHERE WEEKDAY(`datetime`) < 5                               -- test weekday
  AND TIME(`datetime`) BETWEEN '08:00:00' AND '17:00:00';   -- test hours
```

Answer (score 0):

Here we use the following tests:

- weekday < 6 (Saturday) = Monday to Friday
- hour more than 7 (from 08:00:00)
- hour less than 17 (to 16:59:59)

> ```
> create table alarms(  
> id int,
> description   varchar(100),
> date_time datetime);
> insert into alarms values
> (1,'Alarm Activated',
> '2022-01-02 14:00:00'),
> (2,'Alarm Deactivated',
> '2022-01-02 15:00:00'),
> (3,'Alarm Activated',
> '2022-01-03 18:00:00'),
> (4,'Alarm Activated',
> '2022-01-31 11:00:00');
> ```

> ```
> select * 
> from alarms
> where weekday(date_time) < 6
> and 7 < hour(date_time) < 17;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | description     | date_time          
> -: | :-------------- | :------------------
>  3 | Alarm Activated | 2022-01-03 18:00:00
>  4 | Alarm Activated | 2022-01-31 11:00:00
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=73fd5cb0cbbc9fd675a7b3dda75d833d)*