# How do I work out minutes that occurred during office hours (9-5) and out of office hours

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a datetime field that is when an activity starts and an int field with active_time in minutes.

What I want to do is work out in minutes (and then hours /60) how much time the activity was spent during work hours (9-5) and time outside of those hours.

E.G.
Data columns
Datetime: '2022-02-28 16:54:00.000 +0000'.
Active_time in minutes: '20'

Desired output:
Activity time in work hours: '6'
Activity time out of work hours: '14'

Can anyone help?

Many thanks.

Comment: Can you please give us some sample data and expected output.

Comment: @HimanshuKandpal just added above

Comment: I answered a very similar question this afternoon : please see the following link for the logic : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71587214/how-to-get-the-data-only-on-working-hours/71587586#71587586

Comment: Is it possible for the activity time to exceed 16 hours?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT start_time, minutes, time_pre_work, work_time, post_work_time
FROM (
    SELECT *
        ,timeadd('minute', minutes, start_time) as time_end
        ,date_trunc('day', start_time) as day
        ,timeadd('hour', 8, day) as workday_start
        ,timeadd('hour', 17, day) as workday_end
        ,timediff('minute', least(start_time, workday_start), workday_start) as time_pre_work
        ,timediff('minute', greatest(start_time, workday_start), least(workday_end, time_end)) as work_time
        ,timediff('minute', greatest(workday_end, workday_end), greatest(workday_end, time_end)) as post_work_time
    FROM VALUES
        ('2022-02-28 16:54:00.000'::timestamp, 20)
        t(start_time, minutes)
);
```

gives:

| START_TIME | MINUTES | TIME_PRE_WORK | WORK_TIME | POST_WORK_TIME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-02-28 | 16:54:00.000 20 | 0 | 6 | 14 |

### Within day clipping:

And not correctly bounding for multi-days, this data:

```
 FROM VALUES
        ('2022-02-28 16:54:00.000'::timestamp, 20),
        ('2022-02-28 7:54:00.000'::timestamp, 20),
        ('2022-02-28 6:54:00.000'::timestamp, 1000)
        t(start_time, minutes)
```

gives:

| START_TIME | MINUTES | TIME_PRE_WORK | WORK_TIME | POST_WORK_TIME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-02-28 | 16:54:00.000 | 20 | 0 | 6 |
| 2022-02-28 | 07:54:00.000 | 20 | 6 | 14 |
| 2022-02-28 | 06:54:00.000 | 1,000 | 66 | 540 |

### Across days with daily clipping:

```
WITH input_data as (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES
        ('2022-02-28 16:54:00.000'::timestamp, 20),
        ('2022-02-28 7:54:00.000'::timestamp, 20),
        ('2022-02-28 6:54:00.000'::timestamp, 3000)
        t(start_time, minutes)
), range as(
    SELECT row_number() over(order by null)-1 as rn
    FROM TABLE(generator(ROWCOUNT => 100))
), day_condition as (
    SELECT *
        ,timeadd('minute', minutes, start_time) as time_end
        ,date_trunc('day', dateadd('day', r.rn, start_time)) as r_day_start
        ,dateadd('day', 1, r_day_start ) as r_day_end
        ,greatest(r_day_start, start_time) as clip_start
        ,least(r_day_end, time_end) as clip_end
    -- insert logic for "which day is it and what hours it has here"
        ,timeadd('hour', 8, r_day_start) as workday_start
        ,timeadd('hour', 17, r_day_start) as workday_end
    FROM input_data i
    JOIN range r ON r.rn <= datediff(day, start_time, timeadd('minute', minutes, start_time))
) 
SELECT 
    start_time
    ,minutes
    ,r_day_start
    --,clip_start
    --,clip_end
    
    ,timediff('minute', least(clip_start, workday_start), workday_start) as time_pre_work
    ,timediff('minute', greatest(clip_start, workday_start), least(workday_end, clip_end)) as work_time
    ,timediff('minute', greatest(workday_end, workday_end), greatest(workday_end, clip_end)) as post_work_time
FROM day_condition
ORDER BY 1,3;
```

| START_TIME | MINUTES | R_DAY_START | TIME_PRE_WORK | WORK_TIME | POST_WORK_TIME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-02-28 06:54:00.000 | 3,000 | 2022-02-28 00:00:00.000 | 66 | 540 | 420 |
| 2022-02-28 06:54:00.000 | 3,000 | 2022-03-01 00:00:00.000 | 480 | 540 | 420 |
| 2022-02-28 06:54:00.000 | 3,000 | 2022-03-02 00:00:00.000 | 480 | 54 | 0 |
| 2022-02-28 07:54:00.000 | 20 | 2022-02-28 00:00:00.000 | 6 | 14 | 0 |
| 2022-02-28 16:54:00.000 | 20 | 2022-02-28 00:00:00.000 | 0 | 6 | 14 |

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't think of a way to approach this using built in date functions, so this is maybe not the prettiest solution, but the math is there. This converts the start_timestamp/active_time into minutes relative to your business hours

I subtracted 540 to essentially set the time 9:00AM to "minute 0" to make the numbers easier to work with. This makes 5:00PM "minute 480"

Then it's just a matter of subtracting times within and outside of your business hours.

```sql
set startdatetime = '2022-03-23 7:31:00'::timestamp_ntz;
set active_minutes = 125;
set business_start = 0;
set business_end = 480;

select 
-540 + (hour($startdatetime) * 60 + minute($startdatetime)) as start_minute,
start_minute + $active_minutes as end_minute,
-- End time (within business hours) - Start time (within business hours). Can't be less than 0
greatest(0, least(end_minute, $business_end) - greatest(start_minute, $business_start)) as minutes_during_business,
-- End - Start. With any "business minutes" ignored. first for pre-work minutes, then for post-work minutes
least(end_minute, $business_start) - least(start_minute, $business_start)
+ greatest(end_minute, $business_end) - greatest(start_minute, $business_end) as minutes_outside_business,
minutes_during_business / 60 as hours_during_business,
minutes_outside_business / 60 as hours_outside_business;
;
```

This does not work well if your active minutes spans into business hours of the following day. That would take some extra handling.

You could also add on seconds, and convert all of the hardcoded numbers to seconds if you do want that extra granularity.